# What does the form « se rendre compte » mean?

Tags: expressions

> Tu es meme en train de te rendre compte que malgre la deference que tu as pour lui, ce maitre est moins intelligent que toi.

So especially the first part I can't understand as a whole, only bits. So what I get is:

> You are on your way to rendering yourself accountable even against the
>   respect that you have for him, this master is less intelligent than
>   you.

So that's the best that I can translate it, but it makes no sense. Am I missing some other meaning to these expressions.

Btw, this is a phrase from a comic book that I'm currently reading.

Comment: *Se rendre compte* is roughly *to realize*. I think this should help with parsing the rest of the sentence correctly. Adding a comma before *malgré* might also be of some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Stéphane, I can now translate the phrase as:

> You are on the way to realizing that despite your respect for him,
>   your master is less intelligent than you.